# Java: Reading from a URL produces gibberish

Tags: java, html, url, encoding

So I've been trying to read the html code from kickass.to(it works fine on other sites) but all I get is some weird gibberish.
My code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://kickass.to/").openStream()));
            String s = "";
            while ((s=in.readLine())!=null) System.out.println(s);
            in.close();
```

For example:
[image]
Does anyone knows why it does that?
thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by gibberish? I ran your code and I just got the html of the page.

Comment: I added a picture to illustrate.

Comment: Maybe try adding a charset argument like, `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://somesite.com/").openStream(), "UTF-8"));`

Comment: I tried it before, it just turns some of the symbols into question marks...

Comment: Should it be UTF-8? Maybe the site is using some other character set. Imagine the havoc you could cause with a site that returned pages in EBCDIC (and returned an appropriate Content-Type: text/html; charset=EBCDIC header).

Comment: @DavidConrad You're right. My mistake. The charset I used was just an example. Checking the header for the `Content-Type`and the charset is the way to go to see what is being returned

Comment: It is UTF-8, but I still get gibberish...

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is a server that is probably not configured correctly, as it returns its response gzip compressed, even if the client does not send an `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header.

So what you're seeing is the compressed version of the page. To decompress it, pass it through a [GZIPInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
         new GZIPInputStream(new URL("http://kickass.to/").openStream())));
```