# Extracting text from InputStreamReader not working in UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, inputstreamreader

I'm trying to read the following API text page:

> https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?page=1&pagesize=9&fromdate=1221436800&todate=1523318400&order=desc&min=1&max=2000000&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow

using InputStreamReader and I want to extract the text and print it line by line.

The issue is that the format of the text is not recognized as UTF-8. So the output looks ugly like:
????

The code of the method is the following:

```
String testURL = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?page=1&pagesize=9&fromdate=1221436800&todate=1523318400&order=desc&min=1&max=2000000&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow";

            URL url = null;
            try
            {
                url = new URL(testURL);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            InputStream is = null;

            try
            {
                is = url.openStream();
            } catch (IOException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "ISO-8859-1")))
            {
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

I've tried changing the line

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")))
```

to

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
```

or to

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "ISO-8859-1")))
```

Unfortunately, the issue still persists. I would really appreciate any tips so I can solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Similar to [Java: Reading from a URL produces gibberish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067416/java-reading-from-a-url-produces-gibberish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To analyse your problem I tried to download from the given URL by [`curl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL#cURL)
(with option `-i`to see the HTTP response header lines) and got:

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2018 21:48:42 GMT
Content-Length: 85

▒VJ-*▒/▒▒LQ▒210ЁrsS▒▒▒S▒▒▒▒3KR2▒▒R
 K3▒RS▒`J▒sA▒I▒)▒▒E@NIj▒R-g▒▒PP^C
```

The line `Content-Encoding: gzip` tells you that the content is gzip-compressed.

Hence, in your Java program you need to gzip-uncompress the contents.
You can do this simply by replacing the line

```
is = url.openStream();
```

with

```
is = new GZIPInputStream(url.openStream());
```

An even better approach would be to get the actual Content-Encoding
and depending on that decide if you need to decompress the content:

```
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
is = connection.getInputStream();
String contentEncoding = connection.getContentEncoding();
if (contentEncoding.equals("gzip"))
    is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
```